Github actions deploy zip to app service but wwwroot is empty
I've got a nest.js api that I'm trying to deploy via github actions to my Azure web service. Which I've previously had working. But now it's not deploying
My action file looks like this
name: Build and deploy Node.js app to Azure Web App - dev-api

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - dev
    # paths-ignore:
    #   - 'README.md'
    #   - '.husky'
    #   - '.github/**'
    #   - '**/*.csv'
  workflow_dispatch:

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v4.1.1

      - name: Set up Node.js version
        uses: actions/setup-node@v4.0.2
        with:
          node-version: '20.4.0'

      # - name: npm install, build, and test
      #   run: |
      #     npm install -g @nestjs/cli
      #     npm install
      #     npm run build

      - name: Zip artifact for deployment
        run: |
          zip -r release.zip . \
          -x "*.git/*" \
          -x ".vscode/*" \
          -x "src/*" \
          -x "test/*" \
          -x "README.md" \
          -x ".env" \
          -x ".env.example" \
          -x ".env.local" \
          -x ".gitignore" \
          -x ".prettierrc" \
          -x "tsconfig.build.json" \
          -x "tsconfig.json" \
          -x ".github/*"

      - name: Upload artifact for deployment job
        uses: actions/upload-artifact@v4.3.1
        with:
          name: node-app
          path: release.zip

  deploy:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    needs: build
    environment:
      name: 'production'
      url: ${{ steps.deploy-to-webapp.outputs.webapp-url }}
    permissions:
      id-token: write #This is required for requesting the JWT

    steps:
      - name: Download artifact from build job
        uses: actions/download-artifact@v4.1.4
        with:
          name: node-app

      # - name: Unzip artifact for deployment
      #   run: unzip release.zip

      - name: Login to Azure
        uses: Azure/login@v2.0.0
        with:
          client-id: ${{ secrets.AZUREAPPSERVICE_CLIENTID_... }}
          tenant-id: ${{ secrets.AZUREAPPSERVICE_TENANTID_... }}
          subscription-id: ${{ secrets.AZUREAPPSERVICE_SUBSCRIPTIONID_... }}

      - name: 'Deploy to Azure Web App'
        id: deploy-to-webapp
        uses: Azure/webapps-deploy@v3.0.1
        with:
          app-name: 'dev-api'
          slot-name: 'production'
          package: 'release.zip'
          # type: 'zip'
          # clean: true
          # restart: true

      - name: Logout
        run: |
          az logout


And my deployment file looks like this
[config]
SCM_DO_BUILD_DURING_DEPLOYMENT=true

And my web.config looks like this
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--
     This configuration file is required if iisnode is used to run node processes behind
     IIS or IIS Express.  For more information, visit:
    https://github.com/tjanczuk/iisnode/blob/master/src/samples/configuration/web.config
-->
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <!-- Visit http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windowsazure/archive/2013/11/14/introduction-to-websockets-on-windows-azure-web-sites.aspx for more information on WebSocket support -->
        <webSocket enabled="false" />
        <handlers>
            <!-- Indicates that the dist/main.js file is a node.js site to be handled by the iisnode module -->
            <add name="iisnode" path="dist/main.js" verb="*" modules="iisnode" />
        </handlers>
        <rewrite>
            <rules>
                <!-- Do not interfere with requests for node-inspector debugging -->
                <rule name="NodeInspector" patternSyntax="ECMAScript" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="^dist/main.js\/debug[\/]?" />
                </rule>

                <!-- First we consider whether the incoming URL matches a physical file in the /public folder -->
                <rule name="StaticContent">
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="public{REQUEST_URI}" />
                </rule>

                <!-- All other URLs are mapped to the node.js site entry point -->
                <rule name="DynamicContent">
                    <conditions>
                        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="True" />
                    </conditions>
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="dist/main.js" />
                </rule>
            </rules>
        </rewrite>

        <!-- 'bin' directory has no special meaning in node.js and apps can be placed in it -->
        <security>
            <requestFiltering>
                <hiddenSegments>
                    <remove segment="bin" />
                </hiddenSegments>
            </requestFiltering>
        </security>

        <!-- Make sure error responses are left untouched -->
        <httpErrors existingResponse="PassThrough" />
        <!--
      You can control how Node is hosted within IIS using the following options:
        * watchedFiles: semi-colon separated list of files that will be watched for changes to restart the server
        * node_env: will be propagated to node as NODE_ENV environment variable
        * debuggingEnabled - controls whether the built-in debugger is enabled
     See https://github.com/tjanczuk/iisnode/blob/master/src/samples/configuration/web.config for a full list of options
    -->
        <!--<iisnode watchedFiles="web.config;*.js"/>-->
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>

I've also got WEBSITE_RUN_FROM_PACKAGE set to true or 1 in my environment variables. But It just won't deploy my Github actions says it's worked.
I get a successfull deploy with this messagae:
Package deployment using OneDeploy initiated.
{
  id: '7e616a05-6826-47c8-9bf7-bb7f3b1b6ad7',
  status: 4,
  status_text: '',
  author_email: 'N/A',
  author: 'N/A',
  deployer: 'OneDeploy',
  message: 'OneDeploy',
  progress: '',
  received_time: '2024-04-17T12:04:00.9090509Z',
  start_time: '2024-04-17T12:04:02.2551014Z',
  end_time: '2024-04-17T12:04:03.2578212Z',
  last_success_end_time: '2024-04-17T12:04:03.2578212Z',
  complete: true,
  active: true,
  is_temp: false,
  is_readonly: true,
  url: 'https://dev-api.scm.azurewebsites.net/api/deployments/7e616a05-6826-47c8-9bf7-bb7f3b1b6ad7',
  log_url: 'https://dev-api.scm.azurewebsites.net/api/deployments/7e616a05-6826-47c8-9bf7-bb7f3b1b6ad7/log',
  site_name: 'dev-api',
  build_summary: { errors: [], warnings: [] }
}
Deploy logs can be viewed at https://dev-api.scm.azurewebsites.net/api/deployments/7e616a05-6826-47c8-9bf7-bb7f3b1b6ad7/log
Successfully deployed web package to App Service.
App Service Application URL: https://dev-api.azurewebsites.net


Just to test right now it doesn't build the app I just want the app to populate the wwwroot folder

did the workflow run successfully?

In step Deploy to Azure Web App in package section use . in place of release.zip see if it works

you have excluded all the files to be zipped

@VivekVaibhavShandilya So on github actions says it ran. I've downloaded the zip file and it just has the basics for now too. I've also tired using . but will try again

try using uses: azure/webapps-deploy@v2 in step Deploy to Azure Web App

@VivekVaibhavShandilya Just tried that and says it worked again but it didn't work too

As I can see you are excluding multiple files to be zipped. cross check, you are not excluding all the files.
This worked for me.
I am using publish profile
My directory :

yml:
# Docs for the Azure Web Apps Deploy action: https://github.com/Azure/webapps-deploy
# More GitHub Actions for Azure: https://github.com/Azure/actions

name: Build and deploy Node.js app to Azure Web App - nesjswebapp

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - main
  workflow_dispatch:

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v4.1.1

      - name: Set up Node.js version
        uses: actions/setup-node@v4.0.2
        with:
          node-version: '20.x'

      #- name: npm install, build, and test
      #  run: |
      #    npm install
      #    npm run build --if-present
      #   npm run test --if-present

      - name: Zip artifact for deployment
        run: |
          zip -r release.zip . \
          -x "src/*" \
          -x "test/*" \
          -x ".gitignore" \
          -x ".prettierrc" \
          -x "tsconfig.build.json" \
          -x "tsconfig.json" \
          -x ".github/*"

      - name: Upload artifact for deployment job
        uses: actions/upload-artifact@v4.3.1
        with:
          name: node-app
          path: release.zip

  deploy:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    needs: build
    environment:
      name: 'Production'
      url: ${{ steps.deploy-to-webapp.outputs.webapp-url }}
    
    steps:
      - name: Download artifact from build job
        uses: actions/download-artifact@v4.1.4
        with:
          name: node-app

     # - name: Unzip artifact for deployment
     #   run: unzip release.zip
      
      - name: 'Deploy to Azure Web App'
        id: deploy-to-webapp
        uses: azure/webapps-deploy@v3.0.1
        with:
          app-name: 'nesjswebapp'
          slot-name: 'Production'
          package: release.zip
          publish-profile: ${{ secrets.AZUREAPPSERVICE_PUBLISHPROFILE_12717BD1B6BD4CCB9EE716xxxxxxx }}

OUTPUT:

As you can see all the files are upload except excluded files. you can check files for linux web app in adding newui at the end of scm url.


Thanks, I've fixed it so for some reason nestjs was working from dist/main but then its changed to dist/src/main and now it works again
